# armv5tejl compiler problems with char arrays

Tags: arrays, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault, arm

I'm working on an embedded project running with the following specs:

**# uname -a**

Linux FFxAV 2.6.30.10 #mvl-avb-0.6 Thu Jun 28 17:55:44 EDT 2012 armv5tejl GNU/Linux

**# cat /proc/cpuinfo**

Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)

BogoMIPS        : 159.74

Features        : swp half fastmult edsp java

CPU implementer : 0x41

CPU architecture: 5TE

CPU variant     : 0x1

CPU part        : 0x926

CPU revision    : 5

**$ /usr/local/arm-2007q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version**

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc (CodeSourcery Sourcery G++ Lite 2007q3-51) 4.2.1

---

I am compiling lldpd (0.6) for use on this platform and have discovered some new and interesting ways to make my code segfault.

The problem I am experiencing has to do with the allocation of char arrays.

If I allocate in such a manner:

char * opts;
opts = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

The code functions correctly (actually segfaults in a later call, but let's not dwell).

If I do an allocation like so however:

char opts[49];

the code segfaults before any of my debugging even prints. This is all happening at the top of the main method.

```
  5 int main(int argc, char ** argv){ 
  6 
  7     fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", __LINE__);
  8     char bopts [50] = "H:vhkrdxX:m:4:6:I:C:p:M:P:S:i@                    ";
  9     bopts[10] = 'g';
 10 }
```

runs fine in a tiny test program but

```
 1034     char opts [51] = "H:vhkrdxX:m:4:6:I:C:p:M:P:S:i@                    ";
```

segfaults in lldpd.c

I went ahead and pulled the assembly from the allocation for each:

From the simple test program (functional)

```
107     char bopts [50] = "H:vhkrdxX:m:4:6:I:C:p:M:P:S:i@                    ";
108     8424:   e59f3044    ldr r3, [pc, #68]   ; 8470 <main+0x78>
109     8428:   e24b2036    sub r2, fp, #54 ; 0x36
110     842c:   e3a0c032    mov ip, #50 ; 0x32
111     8430:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
112     8434:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
113     8438:   e1a0200c    mov r2, ip
114     843c:   ebffffba    bl  832c <_init+0x44>
```

From lldpd.c

```
5061     char opts [51] = "H:vhkrdxX:m:4:6:I:C:p:M:P:S:i@                    ";
5062     d414:   e59f3918    ldr r3, [pc, #2328] ; dd34 <lldpd_main+0x9d4>
5063     d418:   e51b20bc    ldr r2, [fp, #-188]
5064     d41c:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
5065     d420:   e24b2043    sub r2, fp, #67 ; 0x43
5066     d424:   e3a0c033    mov ip, #51 ; 0x33
5067     d428:   e1a00002    mov r0, r2
5068     d42c:   e1a01003    mov r1, r3
5069     d430:   e1a0200c    mov r2, ip
5070     d434:   ebfff229    bl  9ce0 <_init+0x344>
```

So far I cannot see what is wrong here.

When allocating the array on the heap instead of the stack the program seqfaults when attempting to allocate a sockaddr_un struct on the stack.

from un.h

```
8  struct sockaddr_un {
9      __kernel_sa_family_t sun_family; /* AF_UNIX */
10     char sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX];   /* pathname */
11 };
```

My assumption is that this is the same stack array problem but I am having trouble figuring out exactly what.

Anyway, comments or advice are appreciated. This has been driving me crazy for a couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler aligns the stack var to *end* on an aligned location (see the `sub r2, fp, #67` instruction). This is pretty bizarre IMO, but could be the explanation for the segfault (though I 'm not sure why any code would access a char array using word size). If you can show the exact place of the crash and the call stack, it might become a little clearer.

The easiest solution, I think, would be to upgrade to a newer toolchain (2007 is rather old) and see if it works better; if not, try to make sure that sizes of all local vars are aligned to 4 bytes.